# PyObjC crashes by using NSTableView

Tags: python, pyobjc

I want to make NSTableView with PyObjC.
So I wrote code like below.
This code works, at least, I could see TableView.
But when I activate `tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row:`(the method is commented out in below) python crashes by segmantation fault.

I want to know where I made mistake. Thanks.

```
class WindowController(object):

    def numberOfRowsInTableView_(self, table):
        return 2000

    #def tableView_objectValueForTableColumn_row_(self, table, column, row):
    #    return 'hi'

    def initMainWindow(self):
        windowRect = NSMakeRect(0.0, 0.0, 300.0, 500.0)
        self.window = NSWindow.alloc().initWithContentRect_styleMask_backing_defer_(
                windowRect,
                NSTitledWindowMask
                    | NSClosableWindowMask
                    | NSResizableWindowMask
                    | NSMiniaturizableWindowMask
                    | NSTexturedBackgroundWindowMask,
                NSBackingStoreBuffered,
                False)
        self.window.setDelegate_(self.delegate)
        self.view = self.initView()
        self.window.contentView().addSubview_(self.view)
        self.window.display()
        self.window.orderFrontRegardless()

    def initView(self):
        tableContainer = NSScrollView.alloc().initWithFrame_(NSMakeRect(0,0,300, 500))
        tableView = NSTableView.alloc().initWithFrame_(NSMakeRect(0,0,300,500))
        column1 = NSTableColumn.alloc().initWithIdentifier_("Col1")
        tableView.addTableColumn_(column1)
        tableView.setDelegate_(self)
        tableView.setDataSource_(self)
        tableView.reloadData()

        tableContainer.setDocumentView_(tableView)
        tableContainer.setHasVerticalScroller_(True)
        return tableContainer
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the probrem solved.
I need to implement DataSource Protocol like below:

```
class MyDataSource(NSObject, objc.protocolNamed('NSTableViewDataDource')):
    def numberOfRowsInTableView_(self, table):
        return 1000
    def tableView_objectValueForTableColumn_row_(self, table, column, row):
        return 'xyzzy'
```

And then, in TableViewController class, set DataSource like below:

```
ds = MyDataSource.alloc().init()
myTableView.setDataSource_(ds)
```

Now everything works fine.